# Error en consulta de sql server

Tags: sql-server, tsql

Necesito un listado de empleados donde la suma de sueldos en una empresa sea mayor a 430000

```
select id, nombre, apellido, sueldo,
(select gerencia from gerencia
 where idgerencia=empleado.idgerencia
 and SUM(empleado.sueldo)>430000),
 (select descripcion from educacion
 where ideducacion=empleado.ideducacion)
from empleado
group by idgerencia
order by empleado.apellido
```

Me tira este error:

> Mens. 8120, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 6
> La columna 'empleado.id' de la lista de selección no es válida, porque no está contenida en una función de agregado ni en la cláusula GROUP BY.

Algun salvador?

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que tienes que tener en cuenta cuando haces una pregunta en un foro técnico, deberías de exponer un escenario completo sobre lo que tienes y cual es el resultado deseado. Simplemente con exponer la consulta no es suficiente, porque esta sujeto a interpretaciones de quien la lee y además obligas a quienes te quieran responder a realizar cosas por tí, que ya tendrías que proveer tú.

Por ejemplo, me imagino que el escenario es este.

```
Create Table gerencia
             (
             gerencia int
           , nomEmp   varchar(100)
             );

Create table empleado
             (
             id          int
           , idgerencia  int
           , nombre      varchar(100)
           , apellido    varchar(100)
           , sueldo      int
           , ideducacion int
             );

Create table educacion
             (
             ideducacion int
           , descripcion varchar(100)
             );
GO

Insert into educacion(ideducacion
                    , descripcion)
values
       ( 1, 'FP.' ),
       ( 2, 'Uni' ),
       ( 3, 'ESO' );

Insert into gerencia(gerencia
                   , nomEmp)
values
       ( 1, 'Empresa a' ),
       ( 2, 'Compañía b' ),
       ( 3, 'Grupo c' );

Insert into empleado(id
                   , idgerencia
                   , nombre
                   , apellido
                   , sueldo
                   , ideducacion)
values
   ( 1, 1, 'Ana', 'Flores', 130000, 2 ),
   ( 2, 1, 'Carla', 'Perez', 210000, 3 ),
   ( 3, 1, 'Luis', 'Dias', 120000, 2 ),
   ( 4, 2, 'Jorge', 'Dux', 200000, 1 ),
   ( 5, 2, 'Bea', 'Silva', 80000, 3 ),
   ( 6, 3, 'Lolo', 'Ruiz', 50000, 1 ),
   ( 7, 3, 'Miguel', 'Rox', 450000, 2 );
GO
```

Hay muchas formas de enfrentarse a lo que solicitas. Quizá lo primero sea saber cuales son las empresas donde la suma de los salarios de sus empleados es mayor que 430.000.

Esta información, la tiene completa la tabla de empleado.

```
SELECT sum(empleado.sueldo), empleado.idGerencia 
FROM empleado 
group by empleado.idgerencia
having sum(empleado.sueldo)>430000;
```

[image: Resultado]

Entonces dejando esto un poco a un lado, ya sabemos, que de las empresas 1 y 3, son las adecuadas, por tanto podemos hacer un listado de empleados cuyo empresa sea cualquiera de las de la query anterior.

```
SELECT empleado.*, gerencia.nomEmp, educacion.descripcion
FROM empleado 
    inner join gerencia on empleado.idgerencia = gerencia.gerencia
    inner join educacion on empleado.ideducacion = educacion.ideducacion
Where idGerencia in (

    SELECT  empleado.idGerencia 
    FROM empleado 
    group by empleado.idgerencia
    having sum(empleado.sueldo)>430000
);
```

[image: Result 2]

O lo que es lo mismo. Relacionamos todas las tablas, para obtener toda la información y en el `where` limitamos las `idGerencia` a las que estén en el listado que habíamos visto que teníamos.

Hay un montón de alternativas a esta query, pero quizá es una de las maneras más simples didácticas de implementarla.

**Nota**: Intenta no usar subconsultas como columnas de la query. Aunque en otros motores quizá esto puede ser adecuado, en `SQL Server` te penalizará un montón el rendimiento.