# se me suma una fila de mas que no deberia en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Necesito hacer un script que obtenga un listado de empleados y su nivel educativo con la condición de que se encuentre en una gerencia donde la sumatoria de sueldos de los empleados de dicha gerencia sea mayor a $430.000.

Hice esto:

```
select *, gerencia.gerencia, educacion.descripcion,(
            select SUM(sueldo) from empleado
            group by empleado.idgerencia
            having SUM(sueldo) >= 430000
        ) as total
from empleado join gerencia on empleado.idgerencia=gerencia.idgerencia 
              join educacion on empleado.ideducacion=educacion.ideducacion
order by empleado.apellido
```

Pero me devuelve un valor de 450000 cuando deberia ser 200000.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si se fijan el empleado con id 3 tiene distinta gerencia por la cual no deberia sumar su sueldo

alguna ayuda?

Comment: Pon la estructura de tus tablas

Comment: La subconsulta que estas hacien con el sum estas aplicando el sum a todo, debes de poner el idempleado para que lo puedas relacionar

Comment: La pregunta parece duplicada. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/501279/error-en-consulta-de-sql-server/501454#501454. No te es válida la respuesta???